# Save images from Access database to dropbox folder

Tags: image, ms-access, dropbox

I have a MS Access 2010 application with an item table that stores the image of the item. How can I save this image in a Dropbox folder?

Exemple

```
Table: ItemTable
Fields: ID = 0001, DESCRIPTION = Item1, CATEGORY = C1, CUSTOMER = Cust1,
 FOLDER = CATEGORY & "\" & CUSTOMER, IMAGE = Item1.jpg
```

I need to save the image `Item1.jpg` in a folder `C1`, subfolder `Cust1`, into dropbox. The data type for the `IMAGE` field could be a string data (the image file is located in a folder on the hard drive of the local pc) or could be a OLE object, doesn't matter.

Comment: You say "the image file is located in a folder on the hard drive of the local pc) or could be a OLE object, doesn't matter", but it does matter, it matters quite a bit. Perhaps you should post some code to show what you mean.

Comment: Okay. The image must be a string with the URL of the image file located on the pc local, for exemple, "C:\Images\Img1.jpg".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FileCopy in VBA, for example:

```
FileCopy "C:\Images\Img1.jpg", "Z:\Users\Raul\Dropbox\Public\SavedImg1.jpg"
```